# Commit or Rollback whole set of inserts in multiple tables Python 3 using FastApi

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, transactions, fastapi

I have two tables say User and Enrollment, I want to commit both tables or rollback the whole transaction [no insert in both tables if there is any problem].

using Alchemi Transaction Management yes its easy to put them in one transaction like below

```
db.begin()
user_obj = MyUser(user_name='abc@myemail.com', password='abcd')
db.add(user_obj)
db.commit()
db.refresh(user_obj)

db.begin()
user_enrolment = UserEnrollmentModel(user_id=user_obj.id, role_id= 123)
```

// until we commit user_obj dont get user_id which is required in user_enrolment

but the problem is I need User_Id [PK of User table in Enrollment table as FK].

for MyUser I have Model

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_name = sa.Column(sa.String(), nullable=False)
    password = sa.Column(sa.String(), nullable=False)
    enrolment = relationship("Enrolment", secondary=user_enrolment, backref="user_enrol")
```

but dont have model for Enrolment it is being inserted like

```
user_role_obj = {}
        obj["user_id"] = self.user_id
        obj["enrolment_id"] = self.enrolment_id
 result = db.execute(         ums_user_enrolments.insert().returning(ums_user_enrolment.c.id), obj)
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more? why do you need the primary key for user_id, how are you going to use that, can you show that

Comment: I have updated my code example to show more precisely, user_id is required in user_enrolment commit. until i commit user table data [user_id is auto generated received when we save user] I cannot proceed to commit enrollment data. thats how i cannot achieve atomicity [either User and Enrollment both are saved or none].

Comment: do you have a backref or back_populates in the model? it would be helpful to show the code of both the models here

Comment: you dont need the primary_key to update, you can directly pass the `user_obj` to the value you have a backref in `UserEnrollmentModel`, I dont see `UserEnrollmentModel` so I cant tell which value you need to use, so basically something like `UserEnrollmentModel(......., backref_variable=user_obj)`

Comment: You are right but in my case Enrollment table dont have Model, and it has many to many relationship with User and Roles table.        Native Insert query goes to save data in it. Can we apply Transaction management in this case or what is way around to cater such scenario